# How to append replaced changes to XML node?

Tags: xml, powershell

I'm creating this script, that reads pidgin config, there can be multiple accounts, and then i need to keep first part till @ symbol and change the server, but save function is not appending these changes.

Already tried -replace, setcontent, save, no luck.

XML looks like this:

```xml
<account>
 <account>
  <name>account1@oldserver.com</name>
 </account>
 <account>
  <name>account2@oldserver.com</name>
  </account>
</account>
```

```
$path="$Env:USERPROFILE\AppData\Roaming\.purple\"
$file="$path\accounts.xml"
$myxml = [xml](gc -Encoding utf8 $path\accounts.xml) 
$key = $myxml.account.account.name;

foreach ($name in $key)
{
    $account = $name.split('@')[0] 
    $server = $name.split('@')[1] 
    Write-Host "There is $account on $server"
    $newKey = $account +'@'+$server -Replace "appsrv.domain.com/","openfire.domain.com/"

}

$newKey
$xml.save($file)
```

It outputs succesfully only second account with newly replaced string, not both and it's not saving it.

```
 There is account1 on appsrv.domain.com/ 
 There is account2 on appsrv.domain.com/
 account2@openfire.domain.com/
```

and i want it to save back to xml.
account1@openfire.domain.com

Thanks a lot!
Appreciating help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use xpath.

I don't know how your xml looks exactly but something like that should work:

```
$file="YourPath"
$myxml = [xml](Get-Content -Path $file) 
$myxml.SelectNodes('//account/name') | foreach {
    $account = $_.'#text'.split('@')[0] 
    $server = $_.'#text'.split('@')[1] 
    Write-Host "There is $account on $server"
    $_.'#text'= $account +'@'+$server -Replace "appsrv.domain.com/","openfire.domain.com/"
}
$myxml.Save($file)
```

Comment: Ok, this kind of works, but the problem is that it edits both accounts with first account name.

Comment: and it manipulates both accounts as: 

account2@newserver.com
account2@newserver.com

i want
account1@newserver.com
account2@newserver.com

that's why i have split there to keep existing account name

Comment: I do not see any issue. I updated the code, try again

Comment: Yes, correct, now it outputs both correct, but it's not saving it :/ 
Notepad++ offers to reload - but upon reloading it's same entries.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this time it was my typo, because it was looking for given string, but i jammed my keyboard, and it was different strting, that's why it couldnt find it.

Comment: does the replace rellay work? your should try first `if ($server -match appsrv.domain.com/")`. I tested it and it works

Comment: @IESPOTO no problem. Please mark it as an answer when it solved your problem.

Comment: It solved! Thanks! And marked as correct :) Learned a lot!